# Wordpress simple shortcode content length

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have problem with simple shortcode. its works fine . when there have 80 to 90 word. but if there is more then 90 words then its shows me message like `"connection lost"`. i am working in local host. 
Same code works in wp 3.9 version . i tested this code in twenty twelve theme , version 4.0 . but here also its not worked. 
* i don't have any plugin installed.

```
function extre_shortcode( $atts, $content = nulls) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'hola' => '',

), $atts ) );
return '<div class="formacion"><h2>'.$hola.'</h2></div>';

[extra hola="big content"]
```

please , any help. is it for wp latest version..

Thanks

}

Answer (score 0):

After lot of digging i, i found this solution. i posted in here, hopefully this will help others.

Just add this filter in your functions.php

**remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );**

for more info , follow this [thread](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29450)